# using 'rsync' to clone the Debian OP to another partition and get stuck in the booting after installing Windows 10

Tags: debian, boot, rsync, dual-boot, cloning

I am a newbie to Debian but I got all the basics and I have been using it for the base 4 months.I decided to install windows in a dual-boot but i get to the information that i need to install windows first and then the linux system.

I have 2 hard desks. The fist one is The SSD which is the Debian operating system, and the second one is an HDD. I created a partition to clone the debian system into it and i changed the type to 'ext4' and i used 'rsync' using this instruction

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rsync-clone-file-system-hierarchy

after which, the boot from the new partition works fine and then i can boot from the 2 drives.

BUT, after i clean the SSD and install windows, booting into Deibian on the HHD is stuck on some level and there is a lot of messages that shown in the screen.

I entered the rescue mode and tried to update and upgrade the snapd and and it always shows the error that the file system is read only.

I followed a lot of solution on the internet and chatgpt but it seems like nothing work.

I can enter the file system using a live usb, can i edit or change anything in the files or clone it again?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ These type of issues are why I normally suggest just a new install and restore from backup. Also tests that your backup is complete as you still have old install while testing new install. Then you can erase old install.